# How to add prefix +6 in input when user click on the input text

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I am using angular material(https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) for input.

I want to auto add '+6' when user click on the field to insert phone number

[image]

Currently the '6' prefix only display in front of the form.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <span matPrefix>6&nbsp;</span>
   <input matInput placeholder="Phone Number (Eg: 60181345689)"  required formControlName="contactNo [value]="field_contact">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Do we need to remove the +6 when the user unselect the input

Comment: not necessary... but good if can do that

Comment: Ok, let me know if my answer works! I added the code to handle the clicking of fields to add the prefix

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `pattern` validator :

```
<span matPrefix *ngIf="!myForm.get('contactNo').hasError('pattern')">
```

If you want to show it only on focus :

```
<span matPrefix *ngIf="!myForm.get('contactNo').hasError('pattern') && activeDocumentElement === phoneNumber">
<input #phoneNumber matInput placeholder="Phone Number (Eg: 60181345689)"  required formControlName="contactNo [value]="field_contact">
```

Where

```
get activeDocumentElement() { return document.activeElement; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `focusin` event binding.

On your component.html,

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Click here" (focusin)="addPrefix($event)" [value]="inputValue">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
inputValue: string = '';

addPrefix(event) {
  this.inputValue = '+6'
}
```

This will add the '+6' on the input when the user clicks on the input.

I have made a demo for you over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqgf1v?file=app/input-overview-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `matPrefix` directive to an element inside the  will designate it as the prefix. It will be included within the visual container that wraps the form control as per the Material specification.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <span matPrefix>+6 &nbsp;</span>
    <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="Phone Number">
  </mat-form-field>     
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ReactiveForms`, you should use methods it provides for this...

[See stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-w3j8mf?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)